# Create a bidirectional dismissible widget on stack

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this dismissible widget

[image]

with this code:

```
Container(
      color: AppColors.greyColor.withOpacity(0.3),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: Dimension.paddingM,
            right: Dimension.paddingM,
            top: Dimension.paddingS,
            bottom: Dimension.paddingM),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 69,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(Dimension.borderRadiusAll))),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: Dimension.padding),
                    child: Text(
                      'Start',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: AppColors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: Dimension.padding),
                    child: Text(
                      'End',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: AppColors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Dismissible(
                key: Key('badgeBidirectional'),
                confirmDismiss: (direction) {
                  return Future.value(false);
                },
                onDismissed: (direction) {},
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      height: 60,
                      width: 60,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.circular(Dimension.borderRadiusAll),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Icon(
                        Icons.compare_arrows,
                        color: AppColors.white,
                      )),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

The only problem is that when I try to swipe (in both ways) the red button comes out of the black container, like the example below:

[image]

I think the problem could be the stack or the row but I don't found a valid solution.
There is no plugin that replicates such a thing, so I have to do it myself

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Dismissible has to be inside the Container().

Or you can try to wrap the dismissible in a Positioned :

```
Container(
 // (your code)
),
Positioned(
  top:0,
  bottom:0,
  left: 0,
  right: 0,
  child: Dismissible(
    // (your code)
  ),
),
```

Try to set the right and left values with Dimension.paddingM if that don't match with your Container